# InAppBrowser play video from vimeo in the native video player automatically?

Tags: android, video, cordova, vimeo, inappbrowser

i use PhoneGap 2.9.0. for my android app. in the app i use inappbrowser to display content from my website. The problem is when i tried to play embedded video from vimeo, it doesn't work (When i do the same thing with the phone webbroser the video play). I used for test samsung S2 with android 4.1.2

Can InAppBrowser play video from vimeo in the native video player automatically?

Comment: Got solution for this? Am also looking for a similar solution. question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828091/cordovaframework-7-how-to-play-vimeo-video-directly-on-full-screen-without-u